# Update field with the longest varchar field

Tags: query, where

I need to update on of the varchar fields in a table, but only the record that is the longest varchar (has the most data in it.). I could easily find it with this query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) options
FROM ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
ORDER BY LEN(options) DESC
```

Now I need to update it, but I am quite unexperienced with sql. This is a 2005 ms sql server.

my query for updating:

```
  UPDATE ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
  SET options = REPLICATE(options, 4)
  WHERE TOP(1) ORDER BY LEN(options) DESC
```

This gives me an error to TOP(1) which was quite expected. I just don't know the right way to write this query, how could I get to update only the longest varchar field? The one I've managed to get with my select query. Sadly there is no primary key that I could use in my WHERE.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using top(1), you can simply get max function. And for update you can say where options = (select max(LEN(options) from ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt)

Comment: It makes sense, I am still learning sql. I tried to edit the select according to your comment which turned out as this:
SELECT options
FROM ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
WHERE max(LEN(options)) = LEN(options)
but my WHERE seems to be wrong.

I've tried with 
SELECT max(len(options))
FROM ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
But that just returns the length of the field not the actual field
As for the Update:
  UPDATE ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
  SET options = REPLICATE(options, 4)
  where options = (select max(LEN(options) from ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt)
Syntax error near from

Comment: But this seems to be the right track, maybe you could turn this into an answer?

Comment: Please edit your question with exact query and update statement. I think you are using max in the where clause at left hand side. You should be using it in the right side for which you want to update the value.

Comment: I've managed to update it, I just missed the closing ) of the max function :) Thank you very much! If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that your issue is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function you could write the following to obtain the entry with the longest varchar

```
SELECT 
  MAX(LEN(options))
FROM 
  ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt;
```

This can then be combined with an UPDATE statement to give

```
UPDATE ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
SET
   options = REPLICATE(options, 4)
WHERE
   LEN(options) = (  SELECT 
                     MAX(LEN(options))
                   FROM 
                    ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
               );
```

Alternatively you could use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
;WITH MyTestCTE ( LengthLogngestOption)
AS (
    SELECT 
      MAX(LEN(options))
    FROM 
      ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
   )
UPDATE FRRT
   SET FRRT.Options = REPLICATE(options,4)
FROM
   ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt FRRT
JOIN
   MyTestCTE MTCTE
ON
LEN(FRRT.OPTIONS) = MTCTE.LengthLogngestOption;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct, I'd like to ask how could I modify SELECT 
  MAX(LEN(options))
FROM 
  ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt; to return the value of the field instead of it's lengrh? I am asking this so I can make better SELECTs in the future and drop using TOP()

Comment: You can change your select query to remove len function, you could just run - select options from ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt. If you wish to get max value then use the max function - select max(options) from ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function the SQL function `DATALENGTH` to get the longest value and use a CTE to get the biggest one

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
(
   SELECT options , (options ) AS DLength
   FROM ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
) AS X
ORDER BY DLength DESC
```

In a similar way but not very optimal you can do this

```
UPDATE ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
set options = REPLICATE(options, 4)
where options in(
--Only if options it's unique, if not need to return the ID
SELECT TOP 1 X.options
FROM
(
  SELECT options ,DATALENGTH(options ) AS DLength
  FROM ForrasReportsRicsiTeszt
) AS X
ORDER BY DLength DESC
)
```